# how to concat in mysql server

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Having trouble concat this code in mysql server any ideas?

`DECLARE @letters TABLE(letter VARCHAR(3))`

`INSERT INTO @letters
      VALUES('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K')
            ,('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V')
            ,('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z')`

Comment: The first idea: "Having trouble" isn't a technical explanation for the issue

Comment: Sorry, what i meant was I'm looking for the code of how to concat the code above

Comment: Of course you are having problems.  You are using SQL Server constructs in MySQL.  You are declaring `table` as a table variable, which is SQL Server.

Comment: What do you mean by concat? One single row with all letters?

Comment: Single row and 3 random letters.

Answer (score 0):

Try my suggestion

```
DECLARE @letters tableName (columnName)

INSERT INTO @letters
VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),
        ('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),
        ('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z');
```

Comment: Okay thanks now my only problem is how can i concat 3 random letter in 1 row here's my code. Missing is the concat.

INFO: -queue_length is how many data will show
      -@letter is my table
  
   `SELECT TOP (@queue_length)*
 FROM @letters
 ORDER BY NEWID()`

Comment: maybe this is what you want [random row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)